# TailwindUI tabs dont seem to work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Im trying to use the Tabs from TailwindUI in my react project, but I just cant see it working. I copied the code exactly as it says, but it only shows the tabs header, it doesnt show any of the content for the tabs panel.

the following is how they define the tabs

```
const tabs = [
    { name: 'Sent', href: '#', count: '52', current: true },
    { name: 'Received', href: '#', count: '6', current: false },
]
```

and the tabs code is as follows;

```
<div>
    <div className="sm:hidden">
        <label htmlFor="tabs" className="sr-only">Select a tab</label>
        {/* Use an "onChange" listener to redirect the user to the selected tab URL. */}
        <select
            id="tabs"
            name="tabs"
            className="block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-base focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
            defaultValue={tabs.find((tab) => tab.current).name}
        >
            {tabs.map((tab) => (
                <option key={tab.name}>{tab.name}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div className="hidden sm:block">
        <div className="border-b border-gray-200">
            <nav className="-mb-px flex space-x-8" aria-label="Tabs">
                {tabs.map((tab) => (
                    <a
                        key={tab.name}
                        href="#"
                        className={classNames(
                            tab.current
                                ? 'border-indigo-500 text-indigo-600'
                                : 'border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700',
                            'flex whitespace-nowrap border-b-2 py-4 px-1 text-sm font-medium'
                        )}
                        aria-current={tab.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                    >
                        {tab.name}
                        {tab.count ? (
                            <span
                                className={classNames(
                                    tab.current ? 'bg-indigo-100 text-indigo-600' : 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900',
                                    'ml-3 hidden rounded-full py-0.5 px-2.5 text-xs font-medium md:inline-block'
                                )}
                            >
                                {tab.count}
                            </span>
                        ) : null}
                    </a>
                ))}
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need use a tab state and use onChange listener to make them work

Comment: tailwind UI is meant to provide you only the jsx with tailwind classes, you need to use state to change the tabs.

Comment: Is there any chance you could give me an example ... Im not really sure I understand